# Authenticate in Firebase using Laravel credentials

Tags: algorithm, laravel, jwt, firebase-authentication

According with this tutorial: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server?hl=es#crear_un_token_personalizado

I can authenticate a user in a Firebase app (client side) using a JWT generated in the server.

To achive that, I added a new dependency in my Laravel project: [jwt-auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth)

I have setup correctly the authentication using a regular JWT. But, for authenticate in Firebase I need to generate a particular JWT, with custom parameters described in the tutorial.

I have change the parameters. But it also requires to use the `RS256` algorithm. And I got errors when change the algorithm.

The error says `Could not create token: openssl_pkey_get_details() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given`.

There is a issue reported in the Github of the package, and it tells that I need two passwords (private and public key). But I just have 1 key, taken from the Firebase console.

Someone has implemented the Firebase authentication using credentials from an existing database?

Really I need two passwords to use the mentioned algorithm?

Please give me some ideas. Thank you in advance.

Comment: from the error I would say that you're giving boolean value to the function openssl_pkey_get_details(). Could you provide some code samples? Did you download https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt ?

Comment: I am not using the function ```openssl_pkey_get_details``` directly, but it appears when I change the algorithm to RS256. @boroboris I am using one package for jwt in Laravel (link in the description).

Comment: I don't get it, which algorithm do you want to use? cause it seems to me that RS256 is a default algorithm. From what you've said in you question and comment I think you have a mistake somewhere in your code, but you've overlooked it. Try putting a code sample with false data because I don't know where to start exactly.

Comment: @boroboris When I change the default algorthim from ```HS256``` to ```RS256```, I got an error. Apparently I need a public and private key. But from the firebase console I just have a private key.

Comment: @JCarlos did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

So, we already have token authorization on the backend with tymondesigns/jwt-auth and now we want to utilize our token to sign in into firebase.

**1. Change algorithm**

By default, the package uses a symmetric algo HS256 that encoded/decoded with JWT_SECRET from the environment. Firebase require RS256, so in order to proceed we, obviously going to change the algo to RS256.

Go to *.env* file and add next variables:

```
JWT_ALGO=RS256
JWT_PUBLIC_KEY=credentials/public.key
JWT_PRIVATE_KEY=credentials/private.key
JWT_PASSPHRASE=super_secret
```

Also modify config file *config/jwt.php*:

```
'keys' => [

    'public' => 'file://' . base_path( env('JWT_PUBLIC_KEY') ),

    'private' => 'file://' . base_path( env('JWT_PRIVATE_KEY') ),

    'passphrase' => env('JWT_PASSPHRASE'),
],
```

**2. Fetch service account RSA private and create public**

As you see we configured app to look for keys in your_project/credentials folder, and files name is public.key and private.key. So we need to create a key pair.

```
// Create new dummy private key inside your_project/credentials project
openssl genrsa -out private.key 1024
```

Next open your google service account .json file and copy private_key string to private.key file (actually replace a key), and also replace '\n' symbols to a new line.

And now generate a public key based on google private:

```
openssl rsa -in private.key -pubout -out public.key
```

After the keys are created test your project auth, it must working fine with new RS256 alg.

**3. Create different (second) token for firebase**

Further it occurs to me that there is no way to use singe token to auth users in project and firebase, because required claims for firebase and default jwt-auth conflicts. jwt-auth uses 'sub' to store the id of user, firebase for service_account_email. And potentially there are other problems, so I created a special(second) token for firebase. Add method to User model:

```
/**
 * Creates addiotional jwt token for the firebase
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function firebaseToken()
{
    $googleServiceAccountEmail = env('GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL');
    $time = time();
    $expires = $time + (60 * 60);

    $customClaims = [
        'iss' => $googleServiceAccountEmail,
        'sub' => $googleServiceAccountEmail,
        'aud' => env('GOOGLE_AUD'),
        'iat' => $time,
        'exp' => $expires,
        'uid' => $this->id
    ];

    $payload = JWTFactory::customClaims($customClaims)->make();
    $token = \JWTAuth::encode($payload)->get();

    return $token;
}
```

Return this additional token after login, invitation, registration, etc... And use it to login into firebase on the client side.

Huuuh, I hope guys that my experience and this little "guide" will help you.